# UIscroll view images form NSmutable array?? for iphone

Tags: iphone

i tested local images in UIscroll view that worked but now i am doing somethng else

i have a string (from xml)having all 10 URLS and then i defined a NSmutable array that holds them

now is it possible to extract images from that array and display them in UIscrollview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so your question is not regarding scroll view but regarding displaying images using urls right?

It has been asked many times.

```
NSImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSUrl NSURL URLWithString:MyURL]]];
```

Now use this image as you used your local image. Of course you'll have to write your own loop to show all the images from your mutable array.